# Как подойти к изучению Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Ничего не знаю про Spring, но стоит задача научиться ему за две недели. Как подойти правильно и эффективно к обучению? Книги? Статьи?

Comment: https://habr.com/post/333756/ смотрел? Я не профи, но чекни

Comment: первые ссылки в гугле одно, а ваше личное мнение и совет - другое.

Comment: На официальном сайте к каждому проекту спринга имеется описание и туториалы, изучаете, что бы знать что и где расположено, далее с их помощью делаете стандартный CRUD тестовый проект. Основные проекты спринга - core, data, security, основной принцип - IoC, основные шаблоны проектирования, которые используются в спринге - java enterprise patterns. С помощью спринга можно по разному делать одни и те же вещи, но существует 2 подхода - "по старому" без спринг бута и "по новому", большинство туториалов заточено на новый принцип, поэтому не удивляйтесь, если где-нибудь на работе будет все по другому

Comment: Две недели? У вас есть шансы только если вы гениальный java-программист с большим опытом работы и уже знакомы с DI/IoC. Spring не прост и ооочень объёмен.

Comment: Автору вопроса скорее всего не нужно стать экспертом по спрингу, а хотя бы получить представление о Spring, это вполне реально за две недели. Я бы посоветовал найти простенький туториал, выполнить его, а потом посмотреть Spring-потрошитель Евгения Борисова https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmBr5diz8WA.

Comment: @AndreyDorohovich возможно я просто тупой, но когда я впервые столкнулся со Spring, мне двух недель не хватило, а я к тому времени уже больше пяти лет работал с Java EE.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вам нужна была одна степень понимания Spring, а автору, возможно, другая. Если у автора вопроса собес на джуна через две недели и у него будет пара базовых вопросов по Spring, то две недели хватит, чтобы суметь ответить на них.

Comment: @AndreyDorohovich Меня взяли стажером, но чтобы попасть на работу нужны  большие усилия. Со spring'ом я встречусь бесспорно, но когда - неизвестно, поэтому хочу начать делать хоть что-то, чтобы быть хоть с палкой, чем с кулаками. Спасибо, что дали советы, я их учту.

Answer (score 4):

Я вот нашел [это](http://javastudy.ru/interview/jee-spring-questions-answers/), но на мой взгляд вам мало что даст, поскольку Spring это целая экосистема, вытеснившая Java EE в полном объеме. Вот [здесь](https://dou.ua/lenta/articles/javaee-vs-spring/) идет краткое сравнение двух стэков.

Никакое обучение на мой взгляд не будет целесообразным без чтения документации. Вот [здесь](https://spring-source.ru/docs_simple.php?type=manual&theme=docs_simple&docs_simple=chap01_p02) переведенная документация на русский язык. Если знаете английский, то лучше читать [это](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html) в оригинале.

Вот еще один полезный [ресурс](https://dou.ua/lenta/articles/java-beginner-guide-4/), где очень много всего можно найти.

Comment: Java EE - это зонтичный стандарт, объединяющий в себе множество других стандартов. В частности, Servlets, JPA, Bean Validation и прочие, на которых построен Spring. Так что не вытеснил, а всего лишь предложил альтернативы CDI, MVC, JSF и JAX-RS.

Comment: Изначально был j2ee и на нем все писали до появления Spring. Потом все поменялось, Spring перенесли в отдельную категорию разработчиков.