# С чего начать изучать Spring framework java?

Tags: java, spring

Подскажите с чего лучше начать изучать српинг фреймворк, может быть какие то ресурсы, или литература? Желательно что бы объяснялось достаточно подробно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-java#

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Comment: Когда-то я задавал похожий вопрос, посмотрите, может Вам будет полезно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал начать с чтения [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/), там всё описано очень качественно и подробно. 
Полного и актуального перевода на русский язык по-моему не существует, так что советую читать в оригинале, всё равно без знания английского разработчику сегодня никуда.

Параллельно можно осваивать замечательную книгу [Spring in action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fourth-edition). Советую именно четвёртое издание, так как пятое сильно акцентируется на Spring Boot и реактивном программировании, а это для начала изучения не подходит.

Ещё могу посоветовать сайт [Baeldung.org](https://www.baeldung.com/) - это супер-кладезь решений многих проблем при работе со Spring и не только. Он меня выручал уже много раз.

И очень важно любое чтение закреплять практикой - ставить себе небольшие задачи и решать их написанием кода.